# Не работатет подключение к пользователю postgres в бд postgreSQl на macOS

Tags: postgresql

Сначала всё работало, но как я перезагрузил ноутбук не могу подключится к пользователю postgres, по команде psql -U postgres пишет:
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Видел уже похожие вопросы, но ничего не помогает